# Reducing Different login page created by multi auth into one login page

Tags: laravel-5.3

In My Laravel 5.3 project i used **multi auth** system for four separate users.

So i got **four login pages** for each users created itself.

Now i need a **one single login page** and have to direct it to four user types. can you suggest any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

add some params to url,such as http://aaa.com/login?type=1
change type to you want.
then redirect the page to different pages.

Or,
use ajax,write this logic to js .

Or,
use an iframe to wrap your page...

Don't know what you really want.
Try above.
Seems you are a newbie...